# Загрузка в буфер обмена (Windows) картинки из файла с помощью Lua, или же модулей к нему

Tags: windows, lua, clipboard

Как загрузить в буфер обмена картинку из файла с помощью Lua? Существуют ли модули для Lua, позволяющие это осуществить, или это реализуется базовым функционалом Lua?

Comment: Базовым функционалом не реализуется. Под Windows есть lua модуль [winapi](https://luapower.com/winapi), используя который вы можете работать с буфером обмена. Пример кода загрузки картинки в буфер не гуглится, поэтому это всего лишь комментарий, а не полноценный ответ на вопрос.